# Globally override default layout option in render method Sinatra

Tags: ajax, sinatra, erb

I'm loading in div content from views with AJAX. I want to set the :layout => false in my erb method if request.xhr? is true. I have:

```
get '/' do
  erb :index, :layout => !request.xhr?
end
```

in all of my routes... but this (:layout => !request.xhr?) becomes repetitions and I want to DRY this out.

How would you suggest I remedy this? Should I open Sinatra::Base and override the render method? If so, how? Is there a good way to write a before filter that checks to see if the request coming in is an AJAX request? I feel like I've tried just about everything I can but I am still not getting the desired output of :layout => false if request.xhr? is true

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrote a helper method to DRY up the code (simple solution, baffled this didn't come to me immediately):

```
helpers do
  def render_erb(template)
    erb template, :layout => !request.xhr?
  end
end
```

Now the index route looks like:

```
 get '/' do
   render_erb :index
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `before` filter, or set the layout in `config`:

```
configure :production, :development do
    set :layout, !request.xhr?
end

# or

before do
    set :layout, !request.xhr?
end
```